# How do I change the output of a memo object in fast report?

Tags: delphi, fastreport

My company has recently begun implementing a business management software called Winner Bizz and I am responsible for customising a number of reporting forms within it. The software uses Fast Report to create reports.

I am in the process of customising a sales contract and have encountered a small problem. Our company is split into a number of branches and each branch location has their name and address on the contract. However the data tree in fast report only allows the company ID number.

```
[Alternative details."FK_CompanyID (CUSTOMER)"] (the memo uses (TWideStrings))
```

For example, this returns the value '01'. Is there a way for me to have this change to the name of the branch?

For example: `**If** (the value is '01') **then** (change it to 'company name')`

Alternatively is there a way for me to instruct it to read the value and if it is ('01') then add text to a separate memo?

Comment: You sound like the end user of this software package. You should direct your questions to the vendor.

Comment: I have but their response was "users such as yourself are free to modify the reports with it but it is not something that is supported by us. The idea is that the system uses a set of standard reports across all customers.Based on feedback we will of course update / improve them where necessary.". Therefore it is unlikely that they would provide such a small change.

Comment: @mbki Does each branch use a different installation of the software?  If so, just modify each report statically for each branch.  If the reports are in one central folder, perhaps you could do a specialized login script for each branch, and map each branch to a different reports folder..

Comment: @John Easley Each branch does have a separate installation. Modifying them statically seems like the most straightforward option thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```html
[IIF(<Alternative details."FK_CompanyID (CUSTOMER)"> = '01', 'company name', <Alternative details."FK_CompanyID (CUSTOMER)">]
```